# Alternate component syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I has someone teach me the other day how to create components using the following:

**HelloWorld.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export default function HelloWorld(props)  {
  return (
    <p>
    Hello, world!
    </p>
  );
}
```

I liked it a lot compared to what I find else where. My problem is that I do not see much, if any, sources out there doing this similar thing. I am wanting to convert the following below to something like what is above but I am not so sure how i would do so:

**UserGist.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as $ from 'jquery';

var UserGist = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      username: '',
      name: '',
      company: '',
      location: '',
      email: ''
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    this.serverRequest = $.get(this.props.source, function (result) {
      this.setState({
        username: result.login,
        name: result.name,
        company: result.company,
        location: result.location,
        email: result.email
      });
    }.bind(this));
  },

  componentWillUnmount: function() {
    this.serverRequest.abort();
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li><b>Username:</b> {this.state.username}</li>
          <li><b>Name:</b> {this.state.name}</li>
          <li><b>Comapny:</b> {this.state.company}</li>
          <li><b>Location:</b> {this.state.location}</li>
          <li><b>Email:</b> {this.state.email}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <UserGist source="https://api.github.com/users/potatogopher" />,
  document.getElementById('gist')
);
```

Other files for clarity:
**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import HelloWorld from './HelloWorld';
import UserInfo from './UserInfo';
import UserGist from './UserGist';

export default function App(props)  {
  return (
    <div>
      <HelloWorld />
      <UserInfo />
      <UserGist source="https://api.github.com/users/potatogopher" />,
    </div>
  );
}
```

**main.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import cubbie from 'cubbie'
import App from './components/App';

window.store = cubbie.createStore();

store.on(store.stateEvents, () => {
  render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
  console.log("app rendered")
});
```

Any help would be great!

Comment: What have you tried so far? What specific problems have you had?

Comment: Note that the `HelloWorld.js` you give is an example of a [stateless component](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#stateless-functions), but your `UserGist.js` is a stateful component, which you can [define as an ES6 class](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html#es6-classes)

Comment: @Hamms I went about putting the render part of the UserGist file into a function but I am just lost on how I would go about including the initial state, componentWill/DidMount into my file.

Comment: @Hamms Okay, that is good to know.. Well I guess I want to make it stateless then.

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I see that I want to use the lifecycle method. Also @Hamms mentioned that what I was going above was stateless. If I want to use a lifecycle method I have to use a class.

### edit above

I found a way that is formatted like the way I want it to be but it seems pretty "hacky".

```
function GetData() {
    $.get("https://api.github.com/users/potatogopher", function (result) {
      store.modifyState(state => {
          state.userGist.name = result.name;
      });
    });
}

GetData();

function UserData(props) {
  return(
    <p data-info={props.data}>
      {store.state.userGist[props.data]}
    </p>
  );
}

export default function UserGist(props) {
  return(
    <div>
      <UserData data="name" />
      <UserData data="company" />
    </div>
  );
}
```